# How to hide specific environment when publishing postman collection

Tags: postman

I publish a collection in a particular postman workspace successfully. The issue is that when I view the documentation using the public link, I am able to switch to other environments that are used by other workspace.

How can I publish the particular environment I want so that other environments are not seen publicly?

For instance in this image I want only the first `staging` to be seen and both `local` and the second `staging` not present.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the specific environment you would like to publish with.

[image]

Oh no! all environments are visible publicly :(

[image]

Don't worry! share the link with others, they will only able to see the environment you have selected while publishing the doc.

[image]

The list of environments visible to you because you have logged in with your account.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize that. Actually did the same thing but since I was still logged in I felt that others will be able to see my other environments