# Hide "No Environment" in postman collection

Tags: postman

I have documentation on the postman hosted website. I want to only publish a `stable` environment.

When I select the `stable` branch while publishing, I can also see "No Environment"

[image]

Also tried in an incognito window, as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63247122/10362396)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Seeing the same issue :(

Comment: Hey @zeroanthem86. Nope, still waiting for the fix